# Impurities in HPGe crystals

Tags: semiconductor-physics, simulations, particle-detectors

Is there any way that one can find the impurities existing in an HPGe crystal? This is required for making an accurate simulation of the material of the crystal including the concentrations of Ge and all other constituents with their concentrations.

Comment: High purity Ge crystals have total impurity levels of perhaps $10^{10}$/cm$^{3}$. What kind of a simulation are you proposing that covers that low level of impurities?

Comment: Yes, indeed the detector in use has impurity levels of 10^10 cm^-3. Which gives relative impurities of the order of 10^-12. I was just considering including these in the simulation to check whether there is an effect at all. 
I just need a very good agreement of simulation with experimental data for the efficiency of the detector, in order to use the simulation later for other purposes needing high accuracy.

Comment: The only real question is carrier lifetime. Since there have been no ‘pure’ crystals grown all the data is from high purity crystals. Coupled with lifetime vs impurity concentration data you should be good.